# ggplot2 plot using wesanderson - Continuous value supplied to a discrete scale error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code with dataframe that contain 20 cty groups. I wish to plot/assign to each specific cty value a color based on Wes Anderson color palettes (packages("wesanderson").

Code:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(wesanderson)
 
df <- mpg[, c("displ","cyl", "cty", "hwy" )]
df[-222,]
 
pal <- wes_palette(20, name = "Zissou1", type = "continuous")

ggplot(df, aes(x=hwy, y=displ, group=cyl)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=cty)) + scale_color_manual(values= pal)
```

But I get an error:

```
Error in `train_discrete()`:
! Continuous value supplied to a discrete scale
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Furthermore, As some palette has 4 colors (e.g., GrandBudapest1, GrandBudapest2, Moonrise1, Moonrise2 and Chevalier1) is there a way to combine these 5 to a new palette of 20 colors?

Thanks.

Comment: Most people will not be able to unambiguously differentiate between 20 different colors. They are just too similar at small shapes. Do you need them to be differentiable? Around 8 colors seems to be the practical limit: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17964/how-many-visually-distinct-colors-can-accurately-be-associated-with-a-separate

Comment: True but this is there reason I wish to combine colors which can be distinguished easily. Even if I add shape I will get the "The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more than 6"becomes difficult to discriminate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Convert cty to factor before plotting

```
df$cty <- as.factor(df$cty)
```

[image]

###### Or use a gradient pallete

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = hwy, y = displ, group = cyl)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cty)) +
  scale_color_gradient()
```

[image]